# In self introduction, how can I avoid saying my name twice?

Tags: sentence

Let's take the following conversation:

> `John` - Hey Mike, I am John how are you?
>
> `Mike` - Hi John, I am good. Thanks for asking.
>
> `John` - Let me introduce myself. **I am John** and I am working in ...

Now here, John has said his name twice in the introduction. How can we avoid this or this is ok?

Comment: A trivial answer is: only say it once. This question belongs in https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John has already introduced himself (I am John how are you?).
Why not say 'Let me introduce the subject of my call/our meeting. I am working...'?